# Use of unresolved identifier 'AccessToken' when using Facebook Swift SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-login

I work with Facebook Swift SDK and I'm trying to check if the user is logged in. I get error message `Use of unresolved identifier 'AccessToken'`

My code is:

```
       if let accessToken = AccessToken.current {
            // User is logged in, use 'accessToken' here.

        }
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You should import FacebookCore:

```
import FacebookCore
```

Comment: Facebook's documentation for Swift is bad

Comment: @jakedunc imo all of their documentation is shit and completely off-putting to 'new' developers, same issue with Google

Answer (score 3):

```
import FBSDKCoreKit
import FBSDKLoginKit
```